# Notepad++ how to execute file in cmd Console Using NppExec(plugin)

Tags: notepad++

My Question Is Have Have File Danyial.cs And I Am Compiling It Manually

```
Npp_save
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
csc /t:exe /out:danyial.exe danyial.cs
danyial.exe
```

But This Code Run In notapad++ History Console 
And History Console Not Support Console.Clear();

I Want This Code Run In Cmd Console So What I Do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `npp_run` to run command in "native" console window.

Like this:

```
Npp_save
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
csc /t:exe /out:danyial.exe danyial.cs
Npp_run danyial.exe
```